# What is the attribute property="og:title" inside meta tag?

Tags: html, facebook, properties, meta-tags

I have this extract of website source code:

```
<meta content="This is a basic text" property="og:title" />
```

What does this **property attribute** stand for, and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

`og:title` is one of the open graph meta tags. `og:...` properties define objects in a social graph. They are used for example by Facebook.

`og:title` stands for the title of your object as it should appear within the graph (see here for more http://ogp.me/ )

Comment: @luca — it tells you on the linked to page.

Comment: Is it still necessary to use og, because if I want to improve my google page rankings, I remember reading that page related information should be within first 200-250 characters of the page. If I include og:title, og:description and some other fields how will my page ranking get affected?

Comment: og meta tags shouldn't affect page ranking at all, those influence what will be displayed when you share a link to your page to someone (over fb, messenger, etc), usually a short card-like content will be displayed with a title, image and a short content next to the image

Answer (score 20):

The `property` in meta tags allows you to specify values to property fields which come from a property library. The property library (RDFa format) is specified in the head tag.

For example, to use that code you would have to have something like this in your `<head` tag. `<head xmlns:og="http://example.org/">` and inside the `http://example.org/` there would be a specification for `title` (og:title).

The tag from your example was almost definitely from the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/), the purpose is to specify structured information about your website for the use of Facebook (and possibly other search engines).

Comment: I like the way you went into detail to explain the namespacing. Is it true, though, that the specification for title appears at the 'http://example.org/' address? I was under the impression that the value of the 'xmlns:og' merely had to uniquely identify the namespace, rather than point to it's actual specification. It's a fine point but I thought I'd mention it. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

A degree of control is possible over how information travels from a **third-party website to Facebook** when a page is shared (or liked, etc.). In order to make this possible, information is sent via Open Graph meta tags in the `<head>` part of the website’s code.

Answer (score 2):

Probably part of [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) <strike>for Facebook</strike>.

Edit: guess not only Facebook - that's only one example of using it.