# How do you override generated meta tags?

Tags: html, node.js, web, blogs, hexo

I want to override my Hexo blog's meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Borgez">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://feliborgez.github.io/blog/index.html">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Borgez">
<meta property="og:description" content="The personal blog of Felipe Borgez">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Borgez">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="The personal blog of Felipe Borgez">
```

However, they don't appear to be generated by the theme (or I could change them easily). Where are they being generated?

Answer (score 1):

They are generated by Hexo, which could improve the SEO and social media. Here is an answer how they work: [What is the attribute property="og:title" inside meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535405/what-is-the-attribute-property-ogtitle-inside-meta-tag)

Most of them could be changed in *_config.yml* file, like the `og:title` is from the site title in *_config.yml* file. But some are generated, like the `og:url`.